# How to add a point to a path in Raphael (SVG)

Tags: path, svg, raphael

I'm in a situation where I have a number of paths on the screen, updated several times per seconds. they are extremely simple line paths, each of them is just a simple line on canvas.

I need an efficient way of updating the paths. At the moment, I'm retrieving the path string for each of them, add 'L xx xx', and redraw. It's fine with a small number of lines, but the performance is really bad once the frequency (or the number of paths) increases.

so, the real question is - does Raphael provide a method that would just 'add a point to the path'? 
I'm very new to vectors, not to mention Raphael and svg.

Would be grateful for any help

Thanks
K

Answer (score -2):

I wonder what your doing ;)
Try just Maintenon the updated path and use the "path" attribute on the path
I would be interested to hear if the performance improves
Also you might like to visit my site and play with the demo there for lovely rounded paths

http://irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php?v=2

Look at the technique Catmull Rom Curves it might inspire...
EXCUSE BARE LINKS AND SPELLING iPod!

Comment: Hi. thanks for your answer. I see that on your demo site you're doing some interesting examples, but I struggle to understand the code.
what do you mean by 'Maintenon the updated path'?

Comment: Klon Sorry I was on my iPod "Maintaining" .Did/does the performance improve?